# How can I get full path to files in print queue?

Tags: lpr, lpq

I'm adding files to print queue using lpr. Is there a way to get full path to files in queue or to show the content of them?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. I updated lpr, cups and cups-client and now lpq shows the full path.